# Can't find Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) API 25 ARM System Images

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, arm, android-7.1-nougat

Are there anywhere Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) API 25 (25, not 24) ARM System images (ARM, not x86 Intel) for AVD Manager? Thanks

Unofficial? Beta? Alpha? Any?

Comment: Doesn't look like these are available yet - they don't appear in the Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARM System Images finally appeared in the Android SDK manager
[image: Android SDK manager]